# Bulk update custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, bulk

I'm using built in theme custom post types and I made XML import with posts to this custom post types. Everything work, but not a filter for these custom post types. If I update manually every custom post type (I mean blue update button) then it start displaying in filter. Is there any way how to update all posts ? I don't want to do that manually because it's about 600 posts.

//UPDATE

Here I'm sending an images. This are my custom post types which I imported. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUwF6.jpg and I need update them all. If I click on each imported post and click on update button then it start work. I dont need to change anything, just hit update button and then it's working good in filter. If I dont click on UPDATE button all imported posts are not categorized in filter box which I use on website. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo5Al.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've provided enough information to give you a clear answer.

Perhaps explain what you are doing when you Update the post - are you changing something first?

And - is this a task you only need to do once, or will you need to do it regularly?

Wordpress doesn't have Custom Post Types by default - thats why they are called 'Custom'. So your website may not be 'standard' which will make it harder for people to answer on WPSE without more info.

Comment: Probably content like this that's asking for clarifying info should be a comment to be added to the original question, rather than a new answer ;-)

Comment: I edited my question bellow with screens

Comment: Mozboz - fair point, agreed!. SamM - thanks for the update. Its still hard to know what the cause is likely to be. The Posts appear to be publishing correctly, so thats good. Are you able to post the query code used by the filter? If we could see how the query is constructing its list of posts, it might help.